# Mysql takes up 100% all cpu

Tags: mysql

I made an application with PHP and MySQL. I use VPS with CPU 6 cores and 16GB RAM. After a while the application is very heavy and 100% cpu is used mysql and RAM is not used at all by mysql.
Please tell me the settings on my.ini for the best results, Thank you very much

Comment: Go to your "Big Query Log" and check out why it does it. After that, google stuff like "how to make my database more efficient" to keep going :)

Comment: We can't tell you why your system is behaving the way it is. Something is clearly wrong and these 5 sentences are not going to be enough for us to diagnose it and it's unlikely a change or two to `my.ini` is going to fix it.

Comment: And I dont even think this requires any changes to my.ini, I've been doing this work for a while, and it rarely required changes to it